# Can matplotlib generate bar chart with different legend in same bar?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Can matplotlib generate bar chart with different legend in same bar like what i did in powerbi?

[image]

I want to generate this kind of graph using python. Is there any other plot library can do this?

Comment: Are you simply looking to plot stacked bars?

Comment: Oh yes this is the keyword i want to find. Thanks a lot!